# jQuery confirm.js return result to boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I'm using this [plugin](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#confirm), I wrapped a confirm method into function so I can use it every-time https://jsfiddle.net/8g0j4unj/

```
function askQuestion($msg){
    $.confirm({
        icon : 'fa fa-question-circle-o',
        content : ''+$msg+'',
        theme : 'supervan',
        closeIcon: true,
        animation: 'scale',
        type: 'orange',
        draggable:'true',
        buttons:{
            'Continue' : {
                keys : ['enter'],
                action : function(){
                    return 1;
                }
            },
            'Cancel': {
                keys : ['esc'],
                action: function(){
                    this.close();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to this function it doesn't do any action but continuing the process, how can I return the function to boolean when user confirm or cancel the condition?

```
$(document).on('click','.sample',function(){
    if(askQuestion('Are you sure want to continue without adding a server') == 1){
                alert('Confirmed');
            }
    else{
       alert('Cancelled');
    }

});
```

Comment: Your `askQuestion` function doesn't return anything which means that the `if` condition will always be `false`.

Comment: what do you think about "return true" or "return false"?

Comment: @sachinkumar I alread tried that not worked

Comment: Ohk so try this - return "1" instead of return 1 and compare with "1" instead of 1. OR return "true/false". Overall try place double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I really have no idea why you want to do this while this plugin have `callback` function and you can use it easily. You trying to detect if user click `Confirm` or `Cancel` button, so you don't need to use this:

```
$(document).on('click','.sample',function(){});
```

And your code totally wrong because you want to get returned data from a function on click on a button! but with this?

```
askQuestion('Are you sure want to continue without adding a server')
```

Actually it return nothing. anyway. You can detect simply with `callback`

```
function askQuestion($msg){
    $.confirm({
        icon : 'fa fa-question-circle-o',
        content : ''+$msg+'',
        theme : 'supervan',
        closeIcon: true,
        animation: 'scale',
        type: 'orange',
        draggable:'true',
        buttons:{
            'Continue' : {
                keys : ['enter'],
                action : function(){
                    alert('Confirmed'); // if clicked on confirm
                }
            },
            'Cancel': {
                keys : ['esc'],
                action: function(){
                    this.close();
                    alert('Canceled'); // if clicked on cancel
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g0j4unj/3/)**

Comment: if(askQuestion('Are you sure want to continue without adding a server') == 1), from your example askQuestion is not returning any value, the alert is coming from the 'action : function()' not from inside the if() condition. as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `callback` function.

```js
$(document).on('click','.sample',function(){
askQuestion('Are you sure want to continue without adding a server', function(val){               
           if(val==1){
              alert("Msg: confirmed");
              //do something
           }
           else{
              alert("Msg : rejected");
           }
  });
});

function askQuestion($msg, callback){
$.confirm({
    icon : 'fa fa-question-circle-o',
    content : ''+$msg+'',
    theme : 'modern',
    closeIcon: true,
    animation: 'scale',
    type: 'orange',
    draggable:'true',
    buttons:{
        'Continue' : {
            keys : ['enter'],
            action : function(){
                callback(1);
            }
        },
        'Cancel': {
            keys : ['esc'],
            action: function(){
                this.close();
                callback(0);

            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

This is how `callback` is used,

So instead of using `askQuestion()` inside `if()` statement,
write your code and conditions inside the `callback` function body.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aruntom99/qnru5xcd/4/)